# How to select user in Task Scheduler on Azure AD joined device

Tags: azure, windows-10, azure-active-directory

How to select an Azure AD user account on an Azure AD joined device?

Answer (score 4):

I've just run into this problem and solved it using these steps:

1. Create your task as normal in Task Scheduler. In security options select any local user.
2. Export the task into an xml file
3. Delete the task from Task Scheduler
4. Open cmd line and run `whoami /user` - if you want to run the task as a different user to the currently logged in one, you'll have to adjust this accordingly
5. Open the exported task xml file, modify the `<Principals>` section:

   ```
   <Principals>
   <Principal id="Author">
         <UserId>PUT THE USER ID HERE</UserId>
   ...
   ```
6. Save the edited xml file. Import it into Task Scheduler
7. Task Scheduler will display AzureAD\Username even though you aren't able to choose AzureAD when selecting locations. [See example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlG7k.png)

Comment: For step1, after selecting any local user I get asked the password for that user, even for Guest and I don't have it

Comment: I think the other answers missed the point here - it is not about finding the right name to enter, it is that the interface won't accept AzureAD users. This works around that. It even works when "Run whether user is logged in or not" is selected, as it prompts for the correct user's password when you save the task.

Comment: If your cmd does not recognize `whoami` as a command, you need to start it as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Open a CMD and type:

`whoami`

This wil show your azuread\username

Usually this is `azuread\firstmiddellastname`

That is the username that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the azure ad account that you used to make the azure ad joined device. To find the azure ad user, you could open the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), you could see all the user in the **Azure Active Directory**.

Comment: Thanks @SunnySun.<br />
But when I am search, or select this user with the UPN `AzureAD\<UserName>`, Windows thrown an error that it can not find the user:
https://i.imgur.com/5LhPVLL.png

Comment: You could check the user in the local admin group.